# How to replace this line in javascript with single comparison?

Tags: javascript, syntax

How to replace the following line with a short code of only one comparison?

```
(item.image!==null && typeof(item.image)!==undefined && typeof(item.image)!==NaN && item.image!=='')
```

Comment: Why would an image be NaN or an empty string?

Comment: here, image is a key of item object which should hold the URI of image in the form of string

Answer (score 1):

All conditions of this if can be reduced to this:

`if (item.image)`

Comment: Thanks dude. I heard some people using (!!item.image)...Why is this so?

Comment: @NishanthMekala [Have a read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!)